# JFrame moves to the bottom left corner of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a very strange problem where the moment I run the program it makes a JFrame and places it in the center of the screen (where I want it) and then immediately slides it into the bottom left corner of my screen. I'm using Java 8 on Mac OSX 10.9, and my code is as follows. How do I prevent it from moving and why is it doing so?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: try omitting: frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

Comment: @RayTayek: no, that's not the problem, as that centers the JFrame. The problem exists elsewhere.

Comment: Tyler, if you want our help, I think that you're going to have to create and post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). Please check the link to see what this involves, but essentially you'd be creating and posting a small, actually a **minimal** compilable and runnable program that we can run and that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: Actually, removing that line does solve the problem, but I still want the JFrame to be centered.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: And some idea of which OS your running it would help to...

Comment: Okay I updated the code a little, but that is literally all that is needed to recreate the problem (for me at least).

Comment: What if you take precautions to start your GUI on the Swing event thread? You know, `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});`

Comment: No, but for some reason making it visible before setting the location fixes it. Any reason why?

Comment: Nope, works perfectly fine for me...MacOSX 10.9.5, Java 8.20...

Comment: Huh, it works for me when I export it to a jar, just not in my IDE (Intellij Idea). I guess it's not a Java problem after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, it works when you export it, just not in the IDE. I do not know why this is. However, the issue can be solved by moving `frame.setResizable(false)` to after `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: That's what was figured out in the comments above, but since this is true, I'll mark it as correct so that others can find it more easily.

One thing to note though is that doing this causes the JFrame to flash at (0, 0) before appearing at the center of the screen.

Comment: Interesting; for me, it's the green plus button that flashes.